# React Native App Crashing when opening React Native Developer Tools

Tags: react-native, expo

I have Custom Development Client App build with EAS and it is always crashing when I try to open React Native Debbuger without any log.

Steps to reproduce:

1. eas build --profile development --platform android
2. Start Emulator and download build from link produced in step 1. Open the App.
3. expo start --dev-client
4. Press a │ open Android
5. Press m │ toggle menu
6. Press "Debug Remote JS" on device/emulator
7. React Native Debugger opens in th browser but app is crashing and does it everytime I try to open it again.

Same thing happens on the physical device.

Comment: Did U solve this? I have same issue with ios. having devtools open makes the app crash on reload. No exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

React Native application might be using a library that uses JSI, e.g **React Native Reanimated 2** (https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/#known-problems-and-limitations) or **React Native MMKV** (https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv#limitations).

With these libraries, remote debugging won't execute properly. I'd start on checking of known limitations on your project's 3rd party libs.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that connecting `expo-dev-client` via localhost automatically crashes the app.

Try to use  LAN network and make sure that your device and computer are on the same network.[image]